# Convert word to pdf using vbscript from java in linux machine

Tags: linux, pdf, vbscript

I am creating a word file using jasper report and save the file in the server location and converting the file to the PDF format using `vbscript`.

It is working fine in windows server, but when I am deploying my application in Linux server the word file could not convert it to PDF format. I am also tried with the help of MS Office 2007 and its plugin saveas PDF.

Can any one please help me how to run my application in Linux server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807153/vbscript-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf

Comment: Post any errors you're getting. Also, what interpreter are you using for VBScript? As far as I'm aware the only VBScript interpreters are Windows based.

Comment: May be windows based. i am using the following VBScript.