# vbscript to convert html files to docx

Tags: html, vbscript, converters, docx

I have many html files in c:\temp\ which need to be converted in the same directory to .docx files.
I have Office 2013. So i guess it doesnt need any converter but instead only opening html in word in the background and saving it as a .docx.
I found a script which is converting doc to pdf:
[vbscript to convert word doc to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807153/vbscript-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf)

```
Const wdExportAllDocument = 0
Const wdExportOptimizeForPrint = 0
Const wdExportDocumentContent = 0
Const wdExportFormatPDF = 17
Const wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks = 1

if  Wscript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    ' Get the running instance of MS Word. If Word is not running, Create it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0))
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(WScript.Arguments(0),,TRUE)

    'Export to PDF using preferred settings
    pdf = objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat( _
        WScript.Arguments(1), _
        wdExportFormatPDF, False, wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        wdExportAllDocument,,, _
        wdExportDocumentContent, _
        False, True, _
        wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks _
    )

    'Quit MS Word
    objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
    objWord.Quit(False)
    set objWord = nothing
    set objFSO = nothing
Else
    msgbox("You must select a file to convert")
End If
```

Changing the const wdExportFormatPDF to wdFormatDocumentDefault = 16 throws an error.
Any idea how to open and save as all files in the c:\temp directory?

Comment: `throws an error` - Please always, **always** include details of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **ExportAsFixedFormat** method saves a document as **PDF** or **XPS** format..

Read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-exportasfixedformat-method-word).

For saving your file as `docx`, just use the [SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas(v=office.15).aspx).
It is available for *Office 2013 and later*

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\SomeDir\yourFileName.docx")
```

Comment: For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
        If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "html" Then
   Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.path)
            oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs oFile.path & ".docx", 12
            oDoc.Close
        End If

Comment: now its saving as: filename.html.docx. How to remove .html fro the filename

Comment: @Lucas its because your concatenating the full path of the file (`oFile.path`) to the `".docx"` suffix. Just manipulate the path before concatenating it. Simple example to remove the last 5 characters (which are `".html"`) from your path before concatenating: `pathWithoutHtml = Left(oFile.path, Len(oFile.path) - 5)`. Then concatenate `pathWithoutHtml & ".docx"`